Can't access M2M2 Slamtec 2D Lidar on Unitree Go1 EDU
I have a Go1 Edu equipped with the M2M2 Slamtec 2D LiDAR.
I want to run the SLAMTEC ROS SDK:
(https://developer.slamtec.com/docs/slamware/ros-sdk-en/2.8.2_rtm/)
but it doesn't work.
So, here is my setup:
The M2M2 is mounted on the Go1 Edu and connected with the Go1 ethernet port and powered by USB.
WIFI connection with Go1 established under 192.168.12.1.
I can ping all the Go's nano controllers 192.168.123.xxx.
Tried to run:
roslaunch slamware_ros_sdk slamware_ros_sdk_server_node.launch ip_address:=192.168.11.1

But the error, that 192.168.11.1 (LiDAR default IP) is not reachable.
What did I miss? Do I need to establish a specific connection?
LiDAR SLAM works using the app. SLAMTEC ROS SDK works if I directly connect my PC with the LiDAR.
Since, the 2D LiDAR is a "default" option when buying the Go1 EDU, there should be some documentation, but I can't find anything (except using the app).
